# Laravel Post using axiox Request failed with status code 500

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

Using laravel and vue.js

When I try to send post request using axios I get server error 500

> {Request failed with status code 500}.

**axios method:**

```
async callApi(method, url, dataObj ){
            try {
              return await axios({
                    method: method,
                    url: url,
                    data: dataObj
                });
            } catch (error) {
                // return error.response;

                console.log(error.response.data);
                console.log(error.response.headers);
                console.log(error.toJSON());
            }
        },
```

**Controller:**

```
   public function addTag(Request $request)
    {
        // validate request

        // Insert Tag
        return Tag::create([
            'tagName' => $request->tagName,
        ]);
    }
```

Using the code in my Vue.js page

```
 async addTag(){
            if(this.data.tagName.trim()=='') return this.e('Tag name is required')
            const res = await this.callApi('post', 'app/create_tag', this.data)
            if(res.status===201){
                this.tags.unshift(res.data)
                this.s('Tag has been added successfully!')
                this.addModal = false
                this.data.tagName = ''
            }else{
                if(res.status==422){
                    if(res.data.errors.tagName){
                        this.e(res.data.errors.tagName[0])
                    }

                }else{
                    this.swr()
                }

            }
        },
```

**Tag Model:**

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['id', 'tagName'];

}
```

Comment: You're trying to access request input directly, `$request->input('tagName')` [retrieving input](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input).

Comment: @JuanEizmendi it’s possible to get value from dynamic property - pls read YOUR link more carefully https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-input-via-dynamic-properties . Its not right way, but it is possible.

Comment: @JuanEizmendi 'tagName' doesn't have a default value

Comment: @JuanEizmendi I think `'tagName' => $request->tagName` Worked For me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is you are trying to get $request like

```
'tagName' => $request->tagName,
```

and the right form is

```
'tagName' => $request->["tagName"],
```